# tail -f all files in a directory over time

Tags: macos

I need to monitor a directory for new files that are added (constantly: one or two every 5 seconds are added and deleted).

It would be nice to tail them constantly in terminal, but since this seems unlikely, it would be also good to append all of the tails to a file.  That way when I stop my process I can review all of the files that were added and deleted (I need the contents not the filename).

A shell script will work as well as long as it will run on Mac OSX Lion.

Any help?  I've tried multi-tail and tail -f (but these don't monitor the directory for new files).

Comment: Your question is tagged "linux".  Do you also need this to run in linux?

Comment: Nah, I added that b/c I knew the linux folks would know a command that would work on both. haha

Comment: Also, do you really want to show you the contents of the files, or are you really looking for something that will watch the directory?

Comment: I want the contents of the files.  They are small JSON objects that are constantly coming in and going out.

Comment: I would like to mark an answer, but I have almost less than I started with.

Comment: Any luck with `FNSubscribeByPath`?  What else have you tried since you posted the question?

Comment: I was looking for a command line option or a bash script option.  Can I use those in a simple shell script?

Comment: Yes, if you write a tool that can be executed from a simple shell script.  The problem is, what you need is something event-driven, and there just aren't tools that work like that at in OSX at the shell level.  The operating system certainly *has* the functionality you want, but not the way you want to do it.  My answer, below, suggests what may be the "right" way to do this OSX-style, but you don't want to develop software, you just want a bash script that will run in FreeBSD 4.x userland.  Perhaps if you provided more details about where this data comes from, we can address that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe xtail ?
It could be installed with homebrew or macports on osx.

Answer (score 0):

CoreServices provides methods for watching changes to directories.

[Apple's Carbon documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/Reference/reference.html) is excellent, except that I can't seem to link to a specific function. Search for `FNSubscribeByPath`.

If you really need to look at the contents of the files that get added, then you can write a tool that uses FNSubscribeByPath to tell you when the directory changes and what changed, then `tail -f` the file.

You should probably have something that keeps track of what "tail -f" instances have been launched, so that it can kill them when the files are deleted.  Otherwise, your process table will eventually fill up.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use logstash for this. It will give you a stream of events for a set of inputs (e.g. files) and give you a stream of data you can push to another output (e.g. a file). It will also give you a lot of options for future growth, while being easy to setup in the short term.

http://www.logstash.net/